# My toilet wont flush properly,but it does flush properly like 1 out of 10 flushes

Tags: toilet, drain-waste-vent

Okay, my toilet onny flushes once properly out of like 10 to 20 flushes. I’ve already checked the flapper, toilet handle and chain, and checked and tested the fill valve and float. It all is fine, but my toilet still doesn’t flush. It acts like it’s completely clogged when I try to flush it so I plunged it and then snaked it, and still doesn’t flush. So I then went to my basement and snakes my clean out thinking there might be a clog deeper in the pipes. But none. I did notice air bubbles coming out from underneath where the flapper is found whenever I try to flush the toilet. Could this be caused by a block in my toilet vent? And it you guys think it might, my toilet used to flush fine but recently stopped working properly. But I’m at a loss here. I work for a home improvement company so I run into this kinda stuff almost everyday. But I am no licensed plumber so I don’t know all the ins and outs of that particular trade. I know a lot, but when it comes to drain vents is where I lack in my expertise

Comment: Could be a clogged vent or the holes under the toilet rim might be blocked.  Any other large water holders(full tubs/full sinks) have problems when draining?

Answer (score 1):

The toilet trapway could have an object stuck in it. Give it a visual with one of those little camera-on-a-flex-stick thingies. I've been flummoxed several times by that sort of blockage. There's no connection at all between the flapper and flush channels and the drain/trap channel.